# KendoUI Grid - ForeignKey column not working in PopUp edit mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've searched for all over the place (understatement) for a solution to my case to no avail until now. First, I'll explain my scenario:

- I have an OpenAccess Model exposed as a WCF Data Service (oData v3);
- I have an Kendo MVC Application;
- I have a View with a grid, set for PopUp editing, AJAX Bound;

Before posting some code, let me explain my issue/difficulty. I have an entity with these properties:

- TextoID
- Titulo;
- Corpo;
- TipoTextoID;
- TipoTexto;

There is a ForeignKey column set to the TipoTextoID property which get's correctly populated either in in-line or pop-up mode. But when it comes to changing data, it only works in-line mode. This is my issue I need it to work in a popup, since the "Corpo" property is bound to a KEndoUI Editor.

When in the popup, it does not show the correct value on the dropdown neither changes it when we select it.

Honestly I'm feeling stupid. I tried almost every sample, post, article I could find to no avail and I'm clueless.

I hope someone can help me on this. Thanks in advance to all!

So, here's the code.
The view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<KendoMVC.CostSimulatorService.Texto>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Textos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Textos</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model) // Bind the grid to the Model property of the view
      .Name("Grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Titulo);   //Create a column bound to the "ProductID" property
          //columns.Bound(p => p.IsPrivado).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsPrivado ? checked='checked': '' # class='chkbx' />"); //Create a column bound to the "ProductName" property
          columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsPrivado ? checked='checked': '' # class='chkbx' />"); //Create a column bound to the "ProductName" property
          //columns.Bound(p => p.TiposTexto);
          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.TipoTextoID, 
                                 (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["TiposTexto"], 
                                 "TipoTextoID", 
                                 "Designacao")
                            .Title("Tipo de texto").Width(150);
          columns.Command(command => 
          { 
              command.Edit(); 
              command.Destroy(); 
          }).Width(200);
      })
      .ToolBar(commands => commands.Create())
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("Texto"))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax() //specify server type
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(texto => texto.TextoID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
                model.Field(texto => texto.TextoID).Editable(false); // Make the ProductID property not editable
            })
            .Create(create => create.Action("CreateTexto", "BackOffice"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("ReadTextos", "BackOffice"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateTexto", "BackOffice"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DestroyTexto", "BackOffice")))
     .Pageable() // Enable paging
     .Sortable() // Enable sorting
     .Selectable()
     .Filterable()
     .Scrollable()
         )

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {        
        $("form.k-edit-form").kendoValidator();
    });
</script>
```

Next, then template:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

@model KendoMVC.CostSimulatorService.Texto

Introduza o conteúdo que deseja

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TextoID)
<div id="divWrapper" style="width:99%; float:left;">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Titulo)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Titulo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Titulo)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Corpo)
    </div>
    <div>
        @(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.Corpo))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Corpo)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoTextoID)
    </div>
    <div>
        @*@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.TiposTexto))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TiposTexto)*@
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.TipoTextoID)
            .Name("TiposTexto")
            .DataTextField("Designacao")
            .DataValueField("TipoTextoID")
            .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable) 
           ViewData["TiposTexto"]))
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using KendoMVC.CostSimulatorService;

namespace KendoMVC.Controllers
{
    public partial class BackOfficeController : Controller
    {
        #region CRUD

        #region ReadTextos

        public ActionResult ReadTextos([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            CostSimulatorModel modelo = new CostSimulatorModel(new Uri(@"http://localhost:53212/CostSimulatorModelService.svc/"));

            IQueryable<Texto> textos = modelo.Textos;
            DataSourceResult resultado = textos.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            ViewData["Textos"] = textos;
            return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        #endregion

        #region CreateTexto

        public ActionResult CreateTexto([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Texto texto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CostSimulatorModel modelo = new CostSimulatorModel(new Uri(@"http://localhost:53212/CostSimulatorModelService.svc/"));

                // Create a new Product entity and set its properties from the posted ProductViewModel
                Texto entity = new Texto
                {
                    TextoID = texto.TextoID,
                    Titulo = texto.Titulo,
                    Corpo = texto.Corpo,
                    IsPrivado = texto.IsPrivado,
                    TipoTextoID = texto.TipoTextoID,
                    TiposTexto = texto.TiposTexto
                };
                modelo.AddToTextos(entity);
                // Insert the entity in the database
                modelo.SaveChanges();
                // Get the ProductID generated by the database
                texto.TextoID = entity.TextoID;
            }
            // Return the inserted product. The grid needs the generated ProductID. Also return any validation errors.
            return Json(new[] { texto }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        #endregion

        #region UpdateTexto

        public ActionResult UpdateTexto([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Texto texto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CostSimulatorModel modelo = new CostSimulatorModel(new Uri(@"http://localhost:53212/CostSimulatorModelService.svc/"));

                // Create a new Product entity and set its properties from the posted ProductViewModel
                var entity = new Texto
                {
                    TextoID = texto.TextoID,
                    Titulo = texto.Titulo,
                    Corpo = texto.Corpo,
                    IsPrivado = texto.IsPrivado,
                    TipoTextoID = texto.TipoTextoID,
                    TiposTexto = texto.TiposTexto
                };
                // Attach the entity
                modelo.AttachTo("Textos", entity);
                modelo.UpdateObject(entity);
                // Update the entity in the database
                modelo.SaveChanges();

            }
            // Return the updated product. Also return any validation errors.
            return Json(new[] { texto }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        #endregion

        #region DestroyTexto

        public ActionResult DestroyTexto([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Texto texto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CostSimulatorModel modelo = new CostSimulatorModel(new Uri(@"http://localhost:53212/CostSimulatorModelService.svc/"));

                // Create a new Product entity and set its properties from the posted ProductViewModel
                var entity = new Texto
                {
                    TextoID = texto.TextoID
                    //Titulo = texto.Titulo,
                    //Corpo = texto.Corpo,
                    //IsPrivado = texto.IsPrivado,
                    //TipoTextoID = texto.TipoTextoID
                };
                // Attach the entity
                modelo.AttachTo("Textos", entity);
                // Delete the entity
                modelo.DeleteObject(entity);

                // Delete the entity in the database
                modelo.SaveChanges();
            }
            // Return the removed product. Also return any validation errors.
            return Json(new[] { texto }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an update on this. For now, I got it to partially work. In my controller, if I instead of this: TipoTextoID = texto.TipoTextoID I do this: TipoTextoID = texto.TiposTexto.TipoTextoID, the selected value on the drop down get's update. The downside is that (besides the uglyness of the thing) the change does not get reflected on the grid...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally got this sorted out with the precious help from KendoUI's premium forums.

So, to stop this from happening, one should use the default editor template for the ForeignKeyColumn as an editor for the "TipoTextoID", like so:

Model:

```
[UIHint("GridForeignKey")]
public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
```

Custom popup template:

```
@(Html.EditorFor(m => m.EmployeeID))
```

instead of using @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.TipoTextoID)

Hope this may help others struggling with same thing.

All the best!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will not ask how you figured that out? :) 

I am trying to guess what i should do to make it work also. Howerver I need to use the DropDownList in the Popup, since it is a cascading dropdown with server binding, and other parameters. To get your answer right: what does the [UIHint("GridForeignKey")] actually do, and how it is a part of the solution?

Comment: Using that attribute, you're telling MVC how to proceed. When rendering, it will use the GridForeignKey editor template that should be present in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates. See also @Manish Jain answear on the subject

Comment: @Stargazer Thanks a lot for your question and you answer, I spend about two days to solve this issue .. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Stargazer's answer (Thanks!!!), below custom popup template (Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\GridForeignKey.cshtml) worked for me.

```
@model object

@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
)
```

Also, no need of specifying custom template so do below on grid view:

```
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.PopUp))
```

Last clarification, add below to main grid model (not foreign key viewmodel) also name matches with custom template.

```
[UIHint("GridForeignKey")]
```